# Using XMPP - PEP/PubSub for sensor readings

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

I'm planning to setup some sensors for a project I am working on. I plan to use a simple xmpp client on each device hosting sensors and posting the readings via PEP/PubSub.

I would like to run a program which dynamically displays this sensor data upon receiving the push notifications from the sensor clients.

I intend to communicate on a LAN with 100Mbs connections and several WIFI APs as needed for the sensor locations.

Is XMPP a good choice for a backend?

Would this scale well at say 100 devices running 6-24 sensors each updating every 15-30 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP would certainly be able to handle this use case, and seems a good fit based on the small set of requirements you have shown.  I am assuming that the sensor data is small amounts of textual information.

From what I can see, I would not use PEP though, just straight up pubsub with a single node for all the sensors to publish to.  Pretty much as simple as it gets.

I would think that any XMPP server should be able to easily handle that load.  I know I was able to publish 800,000-1,000,000 items to a persistent node in [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) in about 5 minutes (3.7.2 alpha version).  A non persistent node would probably do a little better.

Comment: By the way, in case it interests, I have read an [article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/application/enterprise/entconfirmation.jsp?arnumber=05345594&icp=false) about some researchers implementing XMPP for Contiki!